# are Butyrate and n-butyrate the same compound

Tags: nomenclature

in the [biomedical literature](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC236418/?page=1) I see references to both butyrate and n-butyrate which seem to be used interchangeably. Are they the same compound? What is the reasoning behind this nomenclature?

Comment: They are about as same as Smith and John Smith.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are compounds. Both are names for the conjugate base of [n-butanoic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butyric_acid), but n-butyrate is more specific in that it specifies the straight chain connectivity explicitly. In principle, butyrate could refer to a branched version, but typically, when the name is ambiguous like this, it defaults to the straight chain variant.

Comment: I guess this answer answers the actual question; however, I don’t think that all statements are correct: Butyrate actually is a compound, “butyrate” cannot refer to a branched isomer, the name “butyrate” is not ambiguous, and generally an ambiguous name does not default to any particular variant. Anyway, it might be worth mentioning that “butyrate” is in accordance with IUPAC nomenclature (although it is not the preferred name) whereas “n-butyrate” is not.

Comment: @Loong "Butyrate" is an actual compound? Or are you talking about a compound word?